# Why I am getting this value error in KNN model?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am applying KNN model on breast cancer wisconsin data but everytime I run the code I get this error:

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [559, 140]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing,cross_validation,neighbors

df=pd.read_csv('breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt')
df.replace('?',-99999,inplace=True)
df.drop(['id'],1,inplace=True)

X=np.array(df.drop(['class'],1))
y=np.array(df['class'])

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
accuracy=clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print(accuracy)

example=np.array([4,2,1,1,1,2,3,2,1])
example=example.reshape(-1,1)

prediction=clf.predict(example)
print(prediction)
```

Comment: Please make your question [*reproducible*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), by including a downloadable link for the data, as well as any extra preprocessing (possibly for inserting column names) you may have done

Answer (score 1):

The output of cross_validation.train_test_split, as per the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html), should be `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test`. Change that line in your code to:

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=cross_validation.train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)
```